# Python code is not calling function in class

Tags: python, database, class

This is the code for an educational snake game which is attempting to change questions as the snake passes the correct answer. Right now, the snake can 'gain a block' by going on the correct answer, the question and correct and wrong answer is not going on to the screen. In the function check_collision() in the main class, I have made code which is meant to blit the new questions and answers on to the screen, but this not happening.

I also have a database which all the questions.

I have tried leaving the `draw_correctanswer()`, `draw_wronganswer()` and `draw_questions()` in the `check_collision()` function but it did not work this way, which is why I copied and pasted its code into the function, and right now it seems that the questions do change for a split second (the questions and answers on the screen seem to randomize through all the questions from my database but it returns to the original question and answers).

How do I get the new questions and answers to go on the screen? I posted all my code, but the important part of the code is the `main()` function and the while loop at the end.

Thank you!!!!

The code is in python 3.8.8

```
class correctanswer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.position()

    def draw_correctanswer(self):
        correct_surface = another_font.render(correct, True, (56,74,12))
        correct_x = cell_number - 13
        correct_y = cell_number - 12
        self.pos = Vector2(correct_x, correct_y)

        correct_rect = pygame.Rect(int(self.pos.x * cell_size), int(self.pos.y * cell_size), cell_size, cell_size)
        screen.blit(correct_surface, correct_rect)

    def position(self):
        self.x = 10

class wronganswer:
    def __init(self):
        self.position2()

    def draw_wronganswer(self):
        wrong_surface = another_font.render(wrong, True, (56,74,12))

        wrong_x = cell_number - 3
        wrong_y = cell_number - 12
        self.pos = Vector2(wrong_x, wrong_y)

        wrong_rect = pygame.Rect(int(self.pos.x * cell_size), int(self.pos.y * cell_size), cell_size, cell_size)
        screen.blit(wrong_surface, wrong_rect)

    def position2(self):
        self.x = 30


class question:
    def __init__(self):
        self.position3()

    def draw_question(self):
        question_surface = another_font.render(ques, True, (56,74,12))
        question_rect = question_surface.get_rect(center = (cell_size * cell_number - 300, cell_size * cell_number - 500))
        screen.blit(question_surface, question_rect)

    def position3(self):
        self.x = 15

class main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.snake = snake()
        self.correctanswer = correctanswer()
        self.wronganswer = wronganswer()
        self.question = question()

    def update(self):
        self.snake.move_snake()
        self.check_collision()
        self.check_fail()

    def draw_elements(self):
        self.draw_grass()
        self.correctanswer.draw_correctanswer()
        self.wronganswer.draw_wronganswer()
        self.question.draw_question()
        self.check_collision()
        self.snake.draw_snake()
        self.draw_score()
        
    def check_collision(self):

        if self.correctanswer.pos == self.snake.body[0]:
            randomindex = random.randint(0,lengthquestion-1)
            ques = str(questiondata[randomindex])
            question_surface = another_font.render(ques, True, (56,74,12))
            question_rect = question_surface.get_rect(center = (cell_size * cell_number - 300, cell_size * cell_number - 500))
            screen.blit(question_surface, question_rect)

            correct = str(correctdata[randomindex])

            correct_surface = another_font.render(correct, True, (56,74,12))
            correct_rect = pygame.Rect(int(self.correctanswer.pos.x * cell_size), int(self.correctanswer.pos.y * cell_size), cell_size, cell_size)
            screen.blit(correct_surface, correct_rect)

            wrong = str(wrongdata[randomindex])

            wrong_surface = another_font.render(wrong, True, (56,74,12))

            wrong_rect = pygame.Rect(int(self.wronganswer.pos.x * cell_size), int(self.wronganswer.pos.y * cell_size), cell_size, cell_size)
            screen.blit(wrong_surface, wrong_rect)
            
            pygame.display.flip()

        if self.wronganswer.pos == self.snake.body[0]:
            self.game_over()

    def draw_score(self):
        score_text = str(len(self.snake.body) - 3)
        score_surface = game_font.render(score_text, True, (56,74,12))
        score_x = cell_size * cell_number - 60
        score_y = cell_size * cell_number - 40
        score_rect = score_surface.get_rect(center = (score_x, score_y))
        screen.blit(score_surface, score_rect)

randomindex = random.randint(0,lengthquestion-1)

correct = str(correctdata[randomindex])
wrong = str(wrongdata[randomindex])
ques = str(questiondata[randomindex])

SCREEN_UPDATE = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(SCREEN_UPDATE,150)

main_game = main()

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == SCREEN_UPDATE:
            main_game.update()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if main_game.snake.direction.y != 1:
                    main_game.snake.direction = Vector2(0,-1)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                if main_game.snake.direction.x != -1:
                    main_game.snake.direction = Vector2(1,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                if main_game.snake.direction.y != -1:
                    main_game.snake.direction = Vector2(0,1)
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                if main_game.snake.direction.x != 1:
                    main_game.snake.direction = Vector2(-1,0)


    screen.fill((50,205,50))

    main_game.draw_elements()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

database.close()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see if functions are executed and later you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables - maybe it change local values but not global one. Simply you have to debug your code - you can use `print()` (it is called "print debuging") or you would have to learn how to use real debuger.

Comment: by the way: there is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - it helps to recognize class in code. And then you can use `main = Main()` instead of `main_game = main()`

Comment: I did that inside the check_collisions() function and the ques, correct and wrong variable would hold the new questions and answers, but it just would not print it onto the screen. Maybe I do this in the main while loop?